# Efficiently pull unknown data, separate, and store in specific format?

Tags: javascript

I've got data I need to sort through, filter, and store in a specific way. I'll explain by showing. Here is the data:

```
var pieData, cakeData, icecreamData;

var desserts = [
    {
        pies: [
            {
                name: "blueberry",
                count: 3
            },
            {
                name: "pumpkin",
                count: 6
            },
            {
                name: "apple",
                count: 9
            }
        ],
        cakes: [
            {
                name: "chocolate",
                count: 3
            },
            {
            name: "foam",
            count: 6
            },
            {
                name: "wedding",
                count: 9
            }
        ],
        icecream: [
            {
                name: "chocolate",
                count: 3
            },
            {
                name: "strawberry",
                count: 6
            },
            {
                name: "mint-chip",
                count: 9
            }
        ],
        date: "2016-01-06T00:00:00"
    },
    {
        pies: [
            {
                name: "blueberry",
                count: 2
            },
            {
                name: "pumpkin",
                count: 4
            },
            {
                name: "apple",
                count: 6
            }
        ],
        cakes: [
            {
                name: "chocolate",
                count: 2
            },
            {
                name: "foam",
                count: 4
            },
            {
                name: "wedding",
                count: 6
            }
        ],
        icecream: [
            {
                name: "chocolate",
                count: 2
            },
            {
                name: "strawberry",
                count: 4
            },
            {
                name: "mint-chip",
                count: 6
            }
        ],
        date: "2016-01-07T00:00:00"
    },
    {
        pies: [
            {
                name: "blueberry",
                count: 4
            },
            {
                name: "pumpkin",
                count: 8
            },
            {
                name: "apple",
                count: 12
            }
        ],
        cakes: [
            {
                name: "chocolate",
                count: 4
            },
            {
                name: "foam",
                count: 8
            },
            {
                name: "wedding",
                count: 12
            }
        ],
        icecream: [
            {
                name: "chocolate",
                count: 4
            },
            {
                name: "strawberry",
                count: 8
            },
            {
                name: "mint-chip",
                count: 12
            }
        ],
        date: "2016-01-08T00:00:00"
    }
];
```

So I've got my data. The data is basically what types of pies, cakes, and icereams there are which can vary in number, name, and count. Each object in desserts is a day, with the date as the last property. I'll go straight to what I want to get out of it and then explain further after that. Here is what I need to get out of it:

```
pieData = [
    {
        name: "blueberry",
        dates: ["2016-01-06T00:00:00", "2016-01-07T00:00:00", "2016-01-08T00:00:00"],
        counts: [3, 2, 4]
    },
    {
        name: "pumpkin",
        dates: ["2016-01-06T00:00:00", "2016-01-07T00:00:00", "2016-01-08T00:00:00"],
        counts: [6, 4, 8]
    },
    {
        name: "apple",
        dates: ["2016-01-06T00:00:00", "2016-01-07T00:00:00", "2016-01-08T00:00:00"],
        counts: [9, 6, 12]
    }
];
cakeData = [
    {
        name: "chocolate",
        dates: ["2016-01-06T00:00:00", "2016-01-07T00:00:00", "2016-01-08T00:00:00"],
        counts: [3, 2, 4]
    },
    {
        name: "foam",
        dates: ["2016-01-06T00:00:00", "2016-01-07T00:00:00", "2016-01-08T00:00:00"],
        counts: [6, 4, 8]
    },
    {
        name: "wedding",
        dates: ["2016-01-06T00:00:00", "2016-01-07T00:00:00", "2016-01-08T00:00:00"],
        counts: [9, 6, 12]
    }
];
icecreamData = [
    {
        name: "chocolate",
        dates: ["2016-01-06T00:00:00", "2016-01-07T00:00:00", "2016-01-08T00:00:00"],
        counts: [3, 2, 4]
    },
    {
        name: "strawberry",
        dates: ["2016-01-06T00:00:00", "2016-01-07T00:00:00", "2016-01-08T00:00:00"],
        counts: [6, 4, 8]
    },
    {
        name: "mint-chip",
        dates: ["2016-01-06T00:00:00", "2016-01-07T00:00:00", "2016-01-08T00:00:00"],
        counts: [9, 6, 12]
    }
];
```

So I need to pass the desserts variable to a function and have it set the pieData, cakeData, and icecreamData variables, declared at the top of the original data, to the array of objects I've shown in the second bit of code.

**A Few Things to Note:**

1. In the output data, the values correspond to the days they were originally assigned in the original data. For example, pieData[0].dates[0] corresponds to pieData[0].counts[0] as it appears in the original data.
2. There could be infinite types of each dessert or none. Meaning there could be 10 different objects in the "pie" array in the original data or none. But there will always be pies, cakes, and icecream arrays, whether they are empty or have a thousand objects in them.
3. I don't know what types of each dessert will come through. It could be anything. So the pie could be named "pumpkin" or it could be named "battery acid".

My only solution I could think of was to do multiple loops and nested loops and just overall too much code. I know there has to be some efficient wizardry to get this done right.

Comment: For that `dates: [], counts: []` thing...I'm wary about trying to make two arrays that, only by constantly maintaining data the correct way, have matching lengths. Wouldn't it be better to have it organized as `orders: [{date: "2012...", count: 3}, {date:...}]` ?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't do it that way. This is actually formatting to pass to a library and they require it in this format. @Katana314

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand the drive to want "minified" code, but I think it's best to keep things readable. Despite your reservations, I think a few nested loops make sense in this case.

Consider the following way of getting the desired result:

```js
var pieData, cakeData, icecreamData;

var desserts = [{pies:[{name:"blueberry",count:3},{name:"pumpkin",count:6},{name:"apple",count:9}],cakes:[{name:"chocolate",count:3},{name:"foam",count:6},{name:"wedding",count:9}],icecream:[{name:"chocolate",count:3},{name:"strawberry",count:6},{name:"mint-chip",count:9}],date:"2016-01-06T00:00:00"},{pies:[{name:"blueberry",count:2},{name:"pumpkin",count:4},{name:"apple",count:6}],cakes:[{name:"chocolate",count:2},{name:"foam",count:4},{name:"wedding",count:6}],icecream:[{name:"chocolate",count:2},{name:"strawberry",count:4},{name:"mint-chip",count:6}],date:"2016-01-07T00:00:00"},{pies:[{name:"blueberry",count:4},{name:"pumpkin",count:8},{name:"apple",count:12}],cakes:[{name:"chocolate",count:4},{name:"foam",count:8},{name:"wedding",count:12}],icecream:[{name:"chocolate",count:4},{name:"strawberry",count:8},{name:"mint-chip",count:12}],date:"2016-01-08T00:00:00"}];


var dessertData= {};

for (var dessertGroup of desserts) {
  for (var item in dessertGroup) {
    // the timestamp is not a dessert, so skip it
    if (item === 'date') { continue; }
    
    if (!dessertData[item]) {
      // this is a new kind of dessert, add it
      dessertData[item] = [];
    }
    
    for (var flavour of dessertGroup[item]) {
      // get the index of the flavour
      var index = dessertData[item].map(function(e) { return e.name; }).indexOf(flavour.name);

      if (index < 0) {
        // this is a new flavour of dessert, add it to the dessert type
        dessertData[item].push({
          name: flavour.name,
          dates: [],
          counts: []
        });
        index = dessertData[item].length - 1;
      }
      
      // append the relevant data to the flavour properties
      dessertData[item][index].dates.push(dessertGroup.date);
      dessertData[item][index].counts.push(flavour.count);
    }
  }
}

// finally, we want 'cakes'   in 'cakeData'
//                  'pies'    in 'pieData'
// and              'icecream in 'icecreamData'

cakeData = dessertData.cakes;
pieData = dessertData.pies;
icecreamData = dessertData.icecream;


console.log("cakeData=", cakeData);
console.log("pieData=", pieData);
console.log("icecreamData=", icecreamData);
```

This is easy to read and modify. Also, it allows for any type of dessert! Why limit yourself to pies, cake, and icecream.

You'll notice that I'm dynamically creating and accessing the properties of `dessertData` by doing stuff like `dessertData[propertyName]`.

Maybe you knew that was possible, but I used javascript for a long time before learning that the `[]` syntax wasn't just for numerical indices. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks. It is readable and works. It's quite similar to the code I began writing, but yours is still cleaner. We are very concerned with efficiency, but this is probably done well enough to work well for us. I'm still curious to see if anyone has a <10 liner solution or something, if for nothing else, but to learn.

Answer (score 1):

This converts it into the format you want

https://jsfiddle.net/sdhjL7dv/

```
var pieData = [], cakeData = [], icecreamData = [];

var desserts = [
    {
        pies: [
            {
                name: "blueberry",
                count: 3
            },
            {
                name: "pumpkin",
                count: 6
            },
            {
                name: "apple",
                count: 9
            }
        ],
        cakes: [
            {
                name: "chocolate",
                count: 3
            },
            {
            name: "foam",
            count: 6
            },
            {
                name: "wedding",
                count: 9
            }
        ],
        icecream: [
            {
                name: "chocolate",
                count: 3
            },
            {
                name: "strawberry",
                count: 6
            },
            {
                name: "mint-chip",
                count: 9
            }
        ],
        date: "2016-01-06T00:00:00"
    },
    {
        pies: [
            {
                name: "blueberry",
                count: 2
            },
            {
                name: "pumpkin",
                count: 4
            },
            {
                name: "apple",
                count: 6
            }
        ],
        cakes: [
            {
                name: "chocolate",
                count: 2
            },
            {
                name: "foam",
                count: 4
            },
            {
                name: "wedding",
                count: 6
            }
        ],
        icecream: [
            {
                name: "chocolate",
                count: 2
            },
            {
                name: "strawberry",
                count: 4
            },
            {
                name: "mint-chip",
                count: 6
            }
        ],
        date: "2016-01-07T00:00:00"
    },
    {
        pies: [
            {
                name: "blueberry",
                count: 4
            },
            {
                name: "pumpkin",
                count: 8
            },
            {
                name: "apple",
                count: 12
            }
        ],
        cakes: [
            {
                name: "chocolate",
                count: 4
            },
            {
                name: "foam",
                count: 8
            },
            {
                name: "wedding",
                count: 12
            }
        ],
        icecream: [
            {
                name: "chocolate",
                count: 4
            },
            {
                name: "strawberry",
                count: 8
            },
            {
                name: "mint-chip",
                count: 12
            }
        ],
        date: "2016-01-08T00:00:00"
    }
];

for(var i = 0; i < desserts.length; i++) {
    var d = desserts[i].date;
  desserts[i].pies.length && save(pieData, desserts[i].pies, d);
  desserts[i].cakes.length && save(cakeData, desserts[i].cakes, d);
  desserts[i].icecream.length && save(icecreamData, desserts[i].icecream, d);
}

function save(destination, items, d) {
    for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    var name = items[i].name;
    var count = items[i].count;
    if(destination[name] === undefined) { destination[name] = {name:'',dates:[],counts:[]}; }
    destination[name].name = name;
    destination[name].dates.push(d);
    destination[name].counts.push(count);
  }
}
console.log(pieData);
console.log(cakeData);
console.log(icecreamData);
```